# auto create tags wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How we can make auto create tags/category from title when publising not save the page?

I try to modified this code:

```
add_action('save_post', 'add_title_as_category');
function add_title_as_category( $postid ) {
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    $post = get_post($postid);
    if ( $post->post_type == 'page') { 
        $term = get_term_by('slug', $post->post_name, 'category');
        if ( empty($term) ) {
            $add = wp_insert_term( $post->post_title, 'category', array('slug'=> $post->post_name) );
            if ( is_array($add) && isset($add['term_id']) ) {
                wp_set_object_terms($postid, $add['term_id'], 'category', true );
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This code work good when editing and then saving the page but not when "publising". I am using another plugin that create the pages and is not supporting the creation of Tags and categories.

I think the problem is the "save_post" but I try other function such as 'publish_post' from wordpress.org too.

If you have any idea on how to achieve this your more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

`publish_post` is in fact correct action to hook into when you want to do something after post has been published. But since you're using some plugin to create pages, you should try hooking into `wp_insert_post`

Comment: I try that already and I get the same result as save_post. thanks for taking time to answering

Comment: @kriendor check how your plugin adds these pages then.

Comment: I try keeping only a plugin for "categories for pages" and am still getting no result .. any other idea ?